# CakePHP contain() method sees belongsToMany over belongsTo of same table

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

So I have the following (simplified) model

```
                                +------------------+
                                | project_statuses |
                                +------------------+
+---------------------+    +----| id               |
| projects            |    |    | name             |
+---------------------+    |    +------------------+ 
| id                  |    |    +---------+                
| name                |    |    | clients |            
| project_statuses_id |----+    +---------+                               
| client_id           |---------| id      |            
+---------------------+         | name    |
           |                    +---------+
         +------------------+      |
         | clients_projects |------+
         +------------------+
         | id               |
         | client_id        |
         | project_id       |
         +------------------+
```

where a project belongs to many clients and a client can have many projects, but only one client (`Projects.client_id`) can take the responsibility for a project. The project status is here just for comparision.

So the associations in my `ProjectsTable.php`, `ClientsTabe.php` and `ProjectStatusesTable.php` look like this

```
// In ProjectsTable.php
$this->belongsTo('ProjectStatuses', [
    'foreignKey' => 'project_status_id',
    'joinType' => 'INNER'
]);
$this->belongsTo('Clients', [
    'foreignKey' => 'client_id',
    'joinType' => 'INNER'
]);
$this->belongsToMany('Clients', [
    'foreignKey' => 'project_id',
    'targetForeignKey' => 'client_id',
    'joinTable' => 'clients_projects'
]);

// In ClientsTabe.php
$this->hasMany('Projects', [
    'foreignKey' => 'client_id'
]);
$this->belongsToMany('Projects', [
    'foreignKey' => 'client_id',
    'targetForeignKey' => 'project_id',
    'joinTable' => 'clients_projects'
]);

// In ProjectStatusesTable.php
$this->hasMany('Projects', [
    'foreignKey' => 'project_status_id'
]);
```

Now in my `projects/index` page I'd like to have a table showing the project id, name, status and responsible. So I thought in something like this

```
// In ProjectsController.php
$this->Projects->find()->select(['Projects.id','Projects.name'])
->contain(['ProjectStatuses' => [
    'fields' => [
      'ProjectStatuses.name',
    ]]])
->contain(['Clients' => [
    'fields' => [
      'Clients.name',
    ]]]);
```

But only `ProjectStatuses.name` is fetched, for `Clients.name` it throws the error `You are required to select the "ClientsProjects.project_id" field(s)` telling me that is looking through the `belongsToMany` association rather than the `belongsTo` one.

In fact, if I just write `->contain('Clients')` instead of specifying the `Clients.name` field it send the following queries

```
SELECT 
 Projects.id AS `Projects__id`, 
 Projects.name AS `Projects__name`, 
 ProjectStatuses.name AS `ProjectStatuses__name` 
FROM 
 projects Projects 
INNER JOIN project_statuses ProjectStatuses ON ProjectStatuses.id = (Projects.project_status_id) 

SELECT 
 ClientsProjects.id AS `Clients_CJoin__id`, 
 ClientsProjects.client_id AS `Clients_CJoin__client_id`, 
 ClientsProjects.project_id AS `Clients_CJoin__project_id`, 
 Clients.id AS `Clients__id`, 
 Clients.name AS `Clients__name`,  
FROM 
 clients Clients 
INNER JOIN clients_projects ClientsProjects ON Clients.id = (ClientsProjects.client_id) 
WHERE 
 ClientsProjects.project_id in (4)
```

How can I tell the query object to get the `Clients.name` through `Projects.client_id` just as I get `ProjectStatuses.name` through `Projects.project_statuses_id` instead of passing by the `ClientProjects`table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Projects table, you have created two associations for Clients, and vice versa. That doesn't work (as The Highlander said, "There can be only one"), and is likely the source of all your problems.

You'll need to change one of those associations in each table. Maybe a Project should `belongsToMany` Clients but only `belongTo` one ResponsibleClient, and a Client should `belongsToMany` Projects and `hasMany` ReponsibleProjects?

Comment: It worked like a charm :) I think now I understood the importance of aliases, thank you so much!